# Prevent DataGridView RowEnter event on load

Tags: c#, winforms

When page is load than datagridview will be bind from database.

I need row enter event for selecting row and based on retriving data from database.

But at load time it should not happen. How can I do this ?

This is my code

```
private void dgStation_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dgStation.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgStation.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with asp.net ?

Comment: this question is from ASP.NET

Comment: then you should tag it with webforms not with winforms I guess, And in asp.net it's gridview not datagridview.

Comment: I think this gotta be a winform, are you sure about asp net part ? Simplest way would be to attach the handler after the load event.

Comment: can anyone give me the solution instead discuss on TAG. As I need solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach the wire handler after the form is loaded, something like this:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnShown(e);
  dgStation.RowEnter += dgStation_RowEnter;
}
```

Make sure to remove the current RowEnter handler from the designer file.

Or just use a loading flag:

```
private bool loading = true;

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnShown(e);
  loading = false;
}

private void dgStation_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (!loading) {
    dgStation.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgStation.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason, a workaround was to check for DataGrid.Focused=true, and then after your data binding code is complete, then manually call DataGrid.Focus() - this way I got one event fired.